# Is "greetings" a good choice in this case?

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for an email salutation which is between informal and formal. The email will be addressed to a company, but instead of be a business-related email or job application, it is aimed to get information about the company.

Searching in Google, I came across with the term **greetings**. Is it an appropriate word for this case? I have the feeling like if it was out-of-date, sounds like if it was from the medieval age.

Comment: You don't really need a salutation at the start of an email message. Just introduce the subject gently, using the degree of formality you judge suitable for your relationship with the company.

Comment: I always expect "..earthlings" when I read "Greetings". How about "Dear Companyname" or "To whom it may concern" the latter being quite old fashioned but better than "Dear Sirs"

Comment: I do use *Dear X* when I'm targeting the email to a specific individual, or when I'm sending a job application and I don't know who will read it, I use *Dear Hiring Manager*. *To whom it may concern* is a salutation I've never understood, I see it as impolite.

Comment: @DavidR always is polite to start with a salutation when the receiver does not know you.

Comment: "*To whom it may concern*" is not impolite, and I wouldn't consider it old-fashioned; it *is* a little vague, and possibly awkward when you are asking/requesting.   I find "*Dear*" to be awkward in a formal setting, but that is just *my* feeling, not a widespread one. // I think this Question needs more details (about the situation), and is a better fit for a different site (ELL or Writer's SE).

Comment: Start here: [Official email](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95604/official-e-mail) and work your way through the linked questions.

Comment: @KitFox before ask this question, I checked those questions out but the goal of these questions is not the same as mine. In overview, those questions are asking for what kind of salutations exist, and the answers are the typical "Dear Sirs", "Dear X", "To whom it may concern". I'm asking for an specific situation where the email neither can be informal nor is intended to be related to any formal activity. And being specific, I have asked about a specific salutation: **greetings**.

Comment: As I said in an comment or post on an earlier related question, what may be considered 'unusual' or impolite in one country may be a common greeting in another country. That is true even between the UK and the US, so is likely to be more so in non-western cultures. Hence the answer to the question will depend on where you are and where the recipient is located - and this is as much a cultural question as an English Language one.

Comment: @TrevorD The email is intended to a company based in UK. I think I'll use a simple Hello or Good Afternoon.

Comment: Don't assume it's afternoon when they read it! Hello' seems fine for here, but, as it's asking a favour, personally I would still use "Dear Sirs".

Answer (score 0):

**Greetings!** or **Salutations!** are excellent choices to find the spot as you put it `between informal and formal`. (Note exclamation mark)

They are formal terms, yet they are also overly exuberant when using an exclamation mark which will display a whimsical approach to your communication whilst remaining formal.

In the situation you are describing I would absolutely start with 'Greetings!' or 'Salutations!' but be warned they have become very generic as many companies want to find that spot you are looking for.

**Greetings** without an exclamation mark sounds like the first thing an alien would say on arrival to earth. See Marvin the Martian for more details :)

Best of luck