# How to address in a formal email

Tags: formality, syntactic-analysis, email, forms-of-address

Can I address Good Morning / Afternoon after addressing 'Dear XYZ,' in a formal email.

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: Welcome to ELU Ankit, this question is a duplicate of [Official e-mail](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95604/official-e-mail). Because you *can* start your e-mail with any words that make sense in the English language, so what you are really asking here is what is the correct way to address a formal e-mail, and that is answered in the linked post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it would not be either formal or natural.

This line in the email is called a pleasantry. Suggestions for appropriate pleasantries in a formal email include:

- I hope you’re well
- I hope all is well
- I hope the day/week is treating
  you well
- I hope all is well since we last spoke